# Adobe AIR App not Install in iOS 6 iPad

Tags: flash, air

i just create ipad app in Flash Professional with 3.4 AIR SDK, but my published .ipa file is not install in iOS 6 ipad

this .ipa is work nice in iOS 5.1 ipad so please solve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

please remove Application from ipad and delete the certificate install from the ipad 
please correct the provisioning profile certificate and make a new ipa and install once again .

its work i have solve this !!!!

Thanks